# Why my query isn't showing correct results?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have many tables but for instance let's consider 2 tables i.e. Employees and FileEntries. I am picking these fields from both tables `EmployeeID,FileStatus,FileName,EmployeeName`.
These both tables have 1 common field i.e. `EmployeeID`. FileEntries can have EmployeeID being present even if it's not in Employees table. So i want to pick all records from both tables but a new field should show 'NotRegistered' if it is not in Employees table.

```
)
@EmployeeID int
)


Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Modify_RejectedFiles] -- '2015-01-06 07:41:00', '2015-01-06 07:41:00',1,3,'','20001018783815'
(  
 @FromDate SMALLDATETIME,  
 @ToDate SMALLDATETIME,  
 @OfficeID INT=0,  --it represents id of a company/branch/organization being logged in
 @Type INT=0,      --it represents type of a user being logged in i.e. 1=orgranization, 2=company, 3=branch
 @EmployerUniqueID VARCHAR(15)='',  
 @EmployeeUniqueID VARCHAR(15)=''  
)  
AS  

BEGIN  

DECLARE @Branches TABLE  
(  
 BranchID INT  
)  

IF @Type = 1  --Organization
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @Branches 
 SELECT BranchID From vw_OrganizationTree WHERE OrganizationID = @OfficeID  --inserts 3 always because we got only 1 organization i.e. 3
END  

IF @Type = 2  --Company
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @Branches 
 SELECT BranchID From vw_OrganizationTree WHERE CompanyID = @OfficeID  --inserts 3 always because we got only 1 company i.e. 3
END  

IF @Type = 3  -- i.e. Branch
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @Branches 
 SELECT BranchID From vw_OrganizationTree WHERE BranchID = @OfficeID  
END  

  Declare @IsRegistered varchar(20)= 'Registered'     

  If ((Select count(*) from RegisteredEmployees where EmployeeUniqueID= @EmployeeUniqueID) <1)
  Begin
   Set @IsRegistered = 'Not Yet'
  End

  Select distinct FE.EmployeeUniqueID, RE.EmployeeName, Empr.EmployerName, Br.BranchName,
          FE.IsRejected, FE.RejectedFileCreationDateTime
          From 
          File_EDREntries FE 
          left Join 
          RegisteredEmployees RE
          ON FE.EmployeeUniqueID = RE.EmployeeUniqueID 
          left Join Employers Empr
          ON RE.Employer_ID = Empr.ID 
          left Join Branches Br
          ON Br.BranchID = Empr.Branch_ID
          WHERE 
          FE.IsRejected = 1                                         --20017128203780
          AND Empr.Branch_ID in (Select BranchID from @Branches)
```

Comment: so what's the problem is? Is there any error?

Comment: It doesn't help that your question uses different names than the code (Employees table = RegisteredEmployees?). Are you asking how to make a NULL EmployeeName appear as 'NotRegistered'?

Answer (score 0):

Use Case when RE.EmployeeUniqueID is null then 'Not Yet' else 'Registered' End in your final select Query